# ASP.NET MVC @Html.EditorFor(model => model.property) But

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, collections, model

What about if I have a navigation property? I have a collection of another model in the model I'm trying to edit. I want to display a list of checkboxes for each object in the collection property. So far, this is what I tried...

```
@{

            foreach (var category in ViewBag.Categories)
            {
                if (Model.Categories.Contains(category))
                {
                    <input type="checkbox" name="selected-categories" value="category.CategoryId" checked="checked" />@category.Name
                }
                else
                {
                    <input type="checkbox" name="selected-categories" value="@category.CategoryId" />@category.Name
                }
            }   
         }
```

But it fails with an EntityCommandExecutionException. In my if statement, how can I access the model.Categories like I do in something like `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)`???

Answer (score 0):

Using a strongly-typed View is the way I'd go.  Create a ViewModel that contains your Model and use this ViewModel for the strongly-typed View.

Domain Model and ViewModel (simplified)

```
public class YourModel
{
    string Category { get ; set ; }
}

public class YourViewModel
{
    public List<string> PossibleCategories { get ; set ; }
    public YourModel YourData { get ; set ; }
}
```

Then the View:

```
@model YourViewModel


@{ 
    foreach (string CurrCategory in Model.PossibleCategories) 
    { 
        if (Model.YourData.Category == CurrCategory)
        { 
            @Html.CheckBox(CurrCategory, new { @checked = "checked" }) 
            @Html.Encode(CurrCategory) <br />
        }
        else 
        {
            @Html.CheckBox(CurrCategory, false) 
            @Html.Encode(CurrCategory) <br />
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I ended up doing a for loop instead and it seems to be working. Thanks again for your assistance though.

Comment: @user1066133 Why use a simple `for` loop on an object that implements `IEnumerable`??

Comment: I've recently just changed it back to a foreach. The reason it crapped out before is because I set ViewBag.Categories = db.Categories; in the controller and not db.Categories.ToList();